# How to use custom errors on IIS with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, webforms, web-config

I have modified my web.config file in my asp.net web application so that I am showing a custom error page:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       ...snip
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="WebForms/ErrorPage.aspx">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="WebForms/ErrorPageNotFound.aspx" />
        </customErrors>        
    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

When I run the site on IIS I get the following error:

```
Error code: 0x800700b7
Config section 'system.web/customErrors' already defined. 
Sections must only appear once per config file. 
See the help topic <location> for exceptions
```

Clearly I have some config hierarchy at play here but I don't know which file I need to look at (I have 276 web.config files on my machine) - can someone point me in the right direction.

When I find the file can I just rem out the top level `customErrors` section or is this going to cause an issue for other web applications on the same machine that don't have `customErrors` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section should be modified on the root web.config

If you re receiving that error, maybe you have several web.config in sub-directories of your main application, you should start checking those to remove them

> Clearly I have some config hierarchy at play here but I don't know which file I need to look at (I have 276 web.config files on my machine) - can someone point me in the right direction.

Why don't you simply use windows search to find documents containing the string *customErrors*

To enable Windows 7 advanced search:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/in-windows-7-i-want-to-search-for-all-files/aadfe1f1-4a33-406b-8e72-bb920efa4f30

Config files hierarchy

1. Global machine. `<windir>\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<ver>\Config\Machine.config`
2. Root Web config. `<windir>\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<ver>\Config\Web.config`
3. Website. `<wwwroot>\Web.config`
4. Web application. `<wwwroot>|IIS Web Site path\<webapp>\Web.config`
5. Folder. `<wwwroot>|IIS Web Site path\<webapp>\<dir>\Web.config`

Comment: And where do I find the root web.config there is nothing in c:\inetpub\wwwroot? I tried an advanced search but it didn't even find my applications web.config file (!)

Comment: I meant the root config file of your application. Any way, I updated my answer to show you the ASP.Net config hierarchy